# How to return a default Intent configuration for Widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I want to return a
default INIntent for my widget. In the automatically generated file, there is an optional method of the `INIntentHandlerProviding` protocol that allows you to specify the default configuration for your widgets.

For me, it looks something like:

`defaultIntentParameter(for intent: ConfigurationIntent) -> MyCustomINObject`

I manage to make this work, but it only works once. I can't change this dynamically based on date or any other parameters.

Has anyone else had experience with this and managed to get around it?

Comment: did you find any solution? i am facing same issue.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? The default option you provide is only used once in the life cycle of a widget: when the user installs it.

Answer (score 1):

/*! @abstract Default values for parameters with dynamic options
@discussion Called to query the parameter default value.
*/
@available(iOS 14.0, macOS 10.16, watchOS 7.0, *)
@objc(defaultChartTypeForConfiguration:)
optional func defaultChartType(for intent: ConfigurationIntent) -> Chart?

In your IntentHandler file, add the default function so will display default as well.
Change the Task to be the parameter from intent
TaskIntent is the name of the Type[image]

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, DynamicTaskIntentHandling {
    func defaultTask(for _: DynamicTaskIntent) -> TaskIntent? {
        TaskIntent(identifier: "default", display: "Test")
    }
```